# Use of range in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

Below is the elastic search query. I need to use both the range and missing in a query.How can I change the below query

```
     {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "missing": {
                "field": "url"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "com_name",
    "website",
    "_foundation._rating"
  ]
}
```

I need to add range to the above query. Kindly help me add the below section to the above query

```
"range": {
      "_foundation._rating": {
        "gte": 1,
        "lte": 4
      }
```

Comment: I edited my question @Val.  I have a basic query which i work on. I need to add "range" to the above query. I tried all possibilities but i encounter some error.

Comment: I've provided an answer below.

Comment: Thanks @Val. I shall try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the query you need is the following, i.e. the `url` field must be missing and the `_foundation._rating` field must be between and 1 and 4 (inclusive):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "missing": {
            "field": "url"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "_foundation._rating": {
              "gte": 1,
              "lte": 4
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "id",
    "com_name",
    "url",
    "_foundation._rating"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the version of your elastic search, if you are using 5.x, you must use exists inside a must_not clause.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Try the below query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "_foundation._rating": {
                                "gte": 1,
                                "lte": 4
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "url"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yeshodhan Kulkarni